# Does not give me the option to "run alongside windows"

Tags: installation

During installation it does not give me the option to "run alongside windows" instead the pop up box gives these options:
1.ERASE DISC
2.ENCRYPT THE NEW UBUNTU INSTALLATION
3.USE LVM
4.SOMETHING ELSE

really am quite new at this and don't know how to manually partition or attach root files which is what the "SOMETHING ELSE" choice does.

Everyone I have talked to and the Ubuntu manual says it gives you a choice to "run alongside windows", does anyone know how to remedy this problem?

I have windows 8 uefi on an inspiron 3520 I have 5 partitions, two are un-allocated 1 with 819 gb. on the C drive there are a few window files mostly windows desktop files "program files, the majority of window files are on a different partition called "ESP" does this help?

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, select the **Something else** option, and in the Unallocated partition, make 3 partitions

> One. around 5 Gbs (swap)
>
> Two. around whatever you want ("/")
>
> Three. around whatever you want too ("home")

** Note: **"/"** and **"home"** are mount points.

It's always recommended to have **"/"** and **"home"** in different partitions.

After you done that, continue with the installation, it should install **grub** during the Ubuntu installation.

In case you didn't know, grub is a boot manager, that will appear whenever you turn on your computer, giving you the option to boot the desired OS.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that!, hopefully it will allow me to break the partition into three!